# what is configuration for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

i am having data which is in different server which is dynamically updating. i haven't implemented elasticsearch. i just want to implement ealsticsearch to all my distributed servers.i want to  create one centralised cluster where i should have to access all shards  and replicas in a different server. i don't know how to implement this. i have read documentations. still i am not getting how to implement for this scenario.how do i define shard's and replica's for this?.what is configuration for production mode?.how do i make it secure?. what is the basic configuration for this ? or where can i get the documentation for this?

Comment: Most of your questions ARE answered in the documentation. You can try using Chef which is a provisioning tool. There is a repo with a cookbook for it here: https://github.com/elastic/cookbook-elasticsearch

Comment: in that chef cookbook everything is written in ruby only. i am using linux mint . how do i configure here?.i am just a beginner. still i am not getting.how do i configure this?.

Comment: Sounds like you need a learn quite a bit before even considering production.  Play around with configuration options yourself and determine what is best.  For security, look at Xpack.